# Antd-mobile- elements too large

Tags: antd

I recently setup a `create-react-app` to work with `antd-mobile`. I had to eject CRA, and change webpack. I got it working with webpack, using the `babel-import-plugin`. I used `["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile", "style": "css" }]`

However, all the elements are very large. They are not the same size as the demo. This is on both mobile & web.

I am on version `antd-mobile: 1.1.4-beta.1` but the same happend on `1.0.0`

My code is in this repo here: https://github.com/yarnball/antd-mobile-create-react-app/

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relaved to the viewport.

1. Remove `<meta viewport`
2. Add this script inside the `<head></head>` tags:

   `!function(e){function t(a){if(i[a])return i[a].exports;var n=i[a]={exports:{},id:a,loaded:!1};return e[a].call(n.exports,n,n.exports,t),n.loaded=!0,n.exports}var i={};return t.m=e,t.c=i,t.p="",t(0)}([function(e,t){"use strict";Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0});var i=window;t["default"]=i.flex=function(e,t){var a=e||100,n=t||1,r=i.document,o=navigator.userAgent,d=o.match(/Android[\S\s]+AppleWebkit\/(\d{3})/i),l=o.match(/U3\/((\d+|\.){5,})/i),c=l&&parseInt(l[1].split(".").join(""),10)>=80,p=navigator.appVersion.match(/(iphone|ipad|ipod)/gi),s=i.devicePixelRatio||1;p||d&&d[1]>534||c||(s=1);var u=1/s,m=r.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');m||(m=r.createElement("meta"),m.setAttribute("name","viewport"),r.head.appendChild(m)),m.setAttribute("content","width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale="+u+",maximum-scale="+u+",minimum-scale="+u),r.documentElement.style.fontSize=a/2*s*n+"px"},e.exports=t["default"]}]);flex(100, 1);`